# change css style of an element by id in iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

i want to change color of a `<p>` that is in an iframe and i tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('iframe').contents().find('#red').css('color','red'); });
</script>
```

its didn't work.
what's the problem?

Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: Is your iframe on same domain because `.contents()` works if the iframe is on same domain? And have you included jQuery library?

Comment: check if there are more than one iframe  in the page you are working on. It's best to use the iframe ID, rather than selecting all iframe elements

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myframe').load(function(){
            $('#myframe').contents().find('#pred').css('color','red'); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<iframe id="myframe" srcdoc="<p id='pred'>Hello</p>">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

The problem occurs only if you try to put the "src" attribute instead of "srcdoc".
To find more about it check below link

[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)